# why does if end my while statement

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

I'm currently learning very basic C (I know PHP/HTML/VBasic) on [learn-c.org](http://learn-c.org) but I'm struggling to understand why an `if` statement causes a `while` statement to leave.  The site says that `continue` causes the while loop to restart, but even omitting this makes my while loop go back to the beginning if an if statement is true.

The code is as follows:

```
int array[] = {1, 7, 4, 5, 9, 3, 5, 11, 6, 3, 4};
int i = 0;

while (i<10) {
    if(array[i] < 5){
        i++;
    }

    if(array[i] > 10){
        break;
    }

    printf("%d\n",array[i]);
    i++;
}
```

I would expect the first round of the while statement to hit the first `if` (as the `array[i]` will be 1, but carry on as there is nothing that says "stop the loop", unless I put `continue;` after the `i++;` so why would hitting an `if` statement make the while loop?  Does that mean I can't have multiple if's being hit in a C while loop (I'm sure you can in PHP, I use `foreach` mainly in PHP)?

Comment: `if` doesn't, `break` does

Comment: the "break" will break to outside the while so when array[i]>10 it will miss the printf and goto after the while loops contents.

Comment: The `break` statement exits your while loop. This is just as true [in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php).

Comment: @GradyPlayer - Please do not edit the question in this way - it no longer makes any sense.

Comment: Sorry, ive removed the break as I understood why it stopped when it hit the value 11, I mean why when it hits the if statement and performs i++; does it not continue the while?  The above code to my human eye looks wrong as the while should run all the while code regardless of if the if is hit?

Comment: @GavinBurke - When editing the question please do not change the code. It changes the question. Just add text to the end e.g. *EDIT* .....  Then people will not get confused

Comment: @Ed Heal - I will do if it's you who has minus 1 me effectively taking 66% of my reputation away?  User3121023, I get:
7
5
9
5
11
6
4

Comment: @GavinBurke: What makes you believe it doesn't continue the rest of the loop body? By the way, you sometimes double-increment `i` in that loop. Is that why you think the output looks "wrong"?

Comment: Reverted the unhelpful edit.

Comment: @GavinBurke - I gave you the -1 as the question no longer made any sense.

Comment: @GavinBurke - Do you understand why your edits are not helpful?

Comment: I think @Blastfurnace is right, I think you're just getting confused about the `++i`. If `i` is `0` at the first iteration, your first `if` statement will increment `i` by `1`, and your `printf()` will therefore print `array[1]` which is `7`, it won't print `1`. The loop is not somehow restarting and mysteriously skipping to `array[1]` without `printf()`ing `array[0]`, you're just changing the value of `i` within it.

Comment: @EdHeal I didn't edit anything.

Comment: @GradyPlayer - I can remember before paul reverted that the break was removed - See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23833268/revisions

Comment: @EdHeal maybe so, but it didn't have anything to do with me... I am now guessing that you just typed at-g and clicked the name that came up.

Comment: @GradyPlayer - My fault should have selected GavinBurke instead.

Comment: @Blastfurnace That was exactly my problem, the i was incrementing twice when the first if was true so it looked like the if was making the loop end when indeed it was making the next number be ignored.  Thanks!  P.S.  Sorry to all for the editing, I was trying to get across I understand the break bit and why the loop ends when hitting 11 but the comments kept coming up with some "Please Wait 1" error, which i am guessing means I need to wait for another comment first (please fix Stackoverflow!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while loop is working as written.

i is 0

the first if is true as array[0] is 1 so i is incremented to 1

the second if is false as array[1] is 7

printf shows 7

i is incremented to 2

back to the top of the while

the first if is true as array[2] is 4 so i is incremented to 3

the second if is false as array[3] is 5

printf shows 5

i is incremented to 4

back to the top of the while....

Comment: Thanks, I see now and that i is incremented either once or twice hence my confusion!

Answer (score 1):

The `break`instruction will immediately end any loop it's called in, that's why your while loop is exiting.

`continue` doesn't exit the loop, it ends the current iteration and starts the next, "continuing" the loop.

Comment: I've removed the break as I understand why the value 11 in the array stops the loop.  What I don't understand is why hitting the if statement causes the while loop to start again instead of continuing down to it's closing bracket?

Comment: @GavinBurke Are you saying you do not see the output of the printf() statement in the while loop ? You should(until you hit the value 11 in the array), if you don't, something is wrong. Post the output you get. When you get to the closing bracket of a while loop, the while loop starts again, and re-evaluates the while condition. `continue` does the same thing, but allows you to restart the while loop before it reaches the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

> The break statement ends execution of the nearest enclosing loop or conditional statement in which it appears.
>   Quote from msdn
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt88dxx6.aspx

when the while function reaches

```
if(array[i] > 10){
break;
```

and i equals 7 the break command will end the execution of the while

Continue:

> The continue statement passes control to the next iteration of the nearest enclosing do, for, or while statement in which it appears, **bypassing any remaining statements in the do, for, or while statement body.**
>   Quote from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ceyyskb.aspx

as written in the quote above, the continue statement will skip(bypass) everything in the while(in your case) and start the next iteration of the while

Answer (score 0):

from: [break Statement (C)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt88dxx6.aspx) you can read:

```
The break statement is frequently used to terminate the processing of a 
particular case within a switch statement. Lack of an enclosing iterative or
switch statement generates an error.
```

i.e. This will terminate the while loop. if the condition is true in your case.

And the `continue` statement you're saying **won't** restart the while loop, it will go to the **next element**.

In your code you have:

```
if(array[i] > 10){
    break;
}
```

For the `11` it will finish the `while` loop, but if you use `continue` like this:

```
if(array[i] > 10){
    i++;
    continue;
}
```

Will "jump" the `11` and go to `6`

Comment: Your `continue` statement here won't jump the 11 and go to 6, because `11 >= 5`, so `i` will never be incremented. You'll go into an infinite loop doing this.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths you're right, didn't noticed it. Edited

Answer (score 0):

Using `break` in while causes the while loop,when i becomes 7(array[7]=11>10) to terminate it won't print on the screen the rest elements of the array